# How can I convert a string to a map in Azure Data Factory/Synapse Data Flow?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a string column in a parquet file:-

`{"name":"bob","age":"35"}`

I need to create separate columns for each data item.

How can I achieve this? Can I convert the string to a map or parse directly to columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [Parse transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/data-flow-parse) to achieve that.

1. Select Single document as Document form. Select `Column_1`, enter `Column_1` as column name, enter `(name as string,age as integer)` as Output column type:
   [image]
2. Data preview is as follows:
   [image]

Comment: Amazing! Fantastic solution, this has really helped me out.